# nginx set-cookie on proxied error

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx in front of a tomcat application server. In some cases, that application sends a HTTP 403 response, together with a `Set-Cookie` header to remove invalid Cookies on the client.

I also set

```
http {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
}
```

because I don't want any upstream errors to be displayed to the client.

I still want those `Set-Cookie` headers to be sent.

It would be okay to send the header with every 403 response, but [`add_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) does not work for that HTTP status.

How do I need to change the configuration to achieve this?

Comment: You can use `add_header` regardless of response code. That is precisely what the `always` parameter is for. Combining that with `error_page 403` should do the trick.

Comment: ah, overlooked the `always` parameter! It would still be nice to use the headers from upstream.

Comment: Any new information on that?

Comment: Especially the cookies from upstream?

Comment: Sadly, nothing new here. Even specifying `proxy_pass_header  Set-Cookie;` did not work for error responses.

Comment: Rudiger: my upstream server set cookie but the browser is not setting the cookie. Nothing shows in my chrome dev tools. Empty and not sure why. Could you take a look and see if you can help me. I have read everything online and still...no cookies in the browser. I posted a wuestion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079271/nginx-proxy-reverse-not-setting-cookie-from-upstream-server-to-the-client-browse

Comment: I really don't care about the cookie being secure or httpOnly. I just want to write/pass the cookie from my upstream server to the browser but it's my first time using nginx and ubuntu. I used iis and never used this stack. It's driving me crazy.